# elementary OS Luna does not recognize my partitions during installation

Tags: system-installation

I am not new to this installation and stuffs but this is the first time I have come across this problem.
       The below image is my partition table from Windows 8.1:

[image: Patition table Windows 8.1 showing C D E drives]

But, when I install any Linux distro; currently trying to install elementary OS Luna(because Freya has graphical glitches on my laptop with broadwell hd 5500 gfx), the installation wizard shows only one partition of my whole 1TB hard drive. It is neither showing the free space nor the C, F and E drives that are present.

[image: Elementary Installation Wizard showing only single 1TB drive]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I suspect that Luna doesn't recognize your partition table. Since Windows is working fine, and other people are able to install Luna I suspect there is something unorindary about your partition. If you have any interesting details you know - please share. E.g. do you use GPT instead of MBR? I can easily believe that Luna does not recognize GPT

Comment: An update should be made available shortly that may fix your issues with Freya, negating the problem. Unfortunately, Luna is almost entirely unsupported at this time.

Comment: Any particular reason you are installing Luna instead of Freya?

Comment: V_Pavel - My partition is MBR only and I tried to install ubuntu 14.04 and Freya in both of their installation wizard it showed the same.

Lewis Goddard - waiting for it. I was using ubuntu besides win8.1 before I formatted my whole drive and installed win8.1 only because the grub was messed up.

@Gabriel it's because of [this](https://plus.google.com/+AshishShekar/posts/WgjWnHYvq9L) link problem I'm unable to use Freya on my Laptop.

Comment: @codekidX ugh that's a *nasty* bug.

Answer (score 1):

Fact you've same problem with ubuntu makes issue a lot more clear.

I think I've found a solution in another discussion. Link to original post is in the bottom. Quote:

> You have two issues. Windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR(msdos)
>   partitioned drives. It looks like drive was originally gpt. And when
>   you install Windows in BIOS boot mode it does not correctly convert to
>   MBR, but leaves a backup gpt partition table. Windows only boots from
>   gpt drives with UEFI, so if you want to convert to gpt partitioning,
>   you have to reinstall Windows in UEFI boot mode, if your hardware is
>   also UEFI capable.
>
> You can remove backup gpt partition table with fixparts. The Linux
>   will see it as MBR without issue. FixParts is the easiest way to
>   remove the stray GPT data. GPT fdisk (gdisk or sgdisk) can do it, but
>   the procedure's a bit more involved.
>
> http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/
>
> But it also looks like you have used all 4 primary partitions. You
>   have to convert one primary to an extended partition, so you can
>   create as many logical partitions as you want inside the extended. Do
>   not create partitions with Windows as it will convert to dynamic
>   partitions which does not work with Linux at all.
>
> [My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-disk-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu)

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/452335/unable-to-recognize-and-create-partitions-for-ubuntu-installation-on-dell-inspir

Comment: V_Pavel rather than simply pointing to a link, it is preferable to present in the answer *here* the steps that fix the issue, even if it's mostly copy/paste from the original answer (which you should still link to)